# Integrating the Webform module in a page

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I want to have a form that will take end user inputs (text, sentence, text of multiple values and an image upload of png or jpeg format).

These inputs would be later stored in database and would be retrieved using views mysql module and displayed in webpage.

I tried to integrate the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module in my page, but it didn't work well with images while displaying through a view. It displays numbers instead of images (actually this is the place where I am facing issues).

Is there any ways that I can fix this, or do I need to build a module from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Display Image in Drupal View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584945/display-image-in-drupal-view)

Comment: If you are going to publish the content of a form submission, then why not use a custom content type instead of webform. This way you can moderate the content and image rendering issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal using [Entityforms](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) module.Using this module you can take input of text as well as image like webform. This module can be integrated with rules and data export etc. for sending mail and downloding submission as like webform.

There are a lot of advantage over webform but it is different form webform.

For more info go through module documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to have an approval process along with Entityforms.  I tried to create what you've mentioned with entityforms and looking incase there is any modules that can help approval process.  I've started using rules and revisioning, but encountering errors.  Any modules or videos ?

Comment: @user3052377 Please Don't ask question for any solution in comment. Edit own question & ask for any other clearification/answer that you want.